# ERROR AL ELIMINAR UN REGISTRO, mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, registro, delete

Intento eliminar un registro y me da el siguiente error:

"Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in"

Lo que no tiene sentido, es que el código que utilizo para la consulta es prácticamente el mismo para eliminar el registro, sin embargo me marca ese error.
Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.
De antemano, gracias.

*Anexo el código:

```
<?php


$servidor = "localhost:3308";
$nombreusuario = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "agendaphp";
$tabla = "datos";

$conexion = new mysqli ($servidor, $nombreusuario, $password, $db);

if($conexion->connect_error){
    die("conexion fallida". $conexion->connect_error);
} 

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];

$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM  datos WHERE Nombre = '$nombre'") or die( mysqli_error($db));

while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){
echo "
 <Center>
 <TABLE border=\"1\">

 <TR>
<TD>Nombre</TD>
<TD>Dirección</TD>
<TD>Teléfono</TD>
<TD>Celular</TD>
<TD>Email</TD>
<TD>Ciudad</TD>
 </TR>




<TR>
 <TD>".$consulta["Nombre"]."</TD>
 <TD>".$consulta["Direccion"]."</TD>
 <TD>".$consulta["Telefono"]."</TD>
 <TD>".$consulta["Celular"]."</TD>
 <TD>".$consulta["Email"]."</TD>
 <TD>".$consulta["Ciudad"]."</TD>


</TABLE>
</Center>";

$borrar = "DELETE * FROM  datos WHERE Nombre = '$nombre'"; 


 mysqli_query($conexion, $borrar) or die( mysqli_error($db));

}


  mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: El mensaje se refiere a esto: `mysqli_error($db)`, el parámetro que debes pasar ahí es la conexión, pero estás pasando la cadena `$db`, debes cambiarlo por esto: `mysqli_error($conexion)`  entonces sí te mostrará qué error está ocurriendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!